# Testing Existence of a Sparse Array Element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

What's the best way to test for the existence of an array element in a structure several layers deep? For instance:

```
if (typeof arr[a][b][c] === 'undefined') { ...do something... }
```

If [a] or [b] don't exist, we won't be able to test for [c].

Are there underscore or lodash functions to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you need it in many places you can create a function:

```
function get(obj, props) {
  return props.reduce(function(x, p) { return x && x[p] ? x[p] : null }, obj)
}

if (get(arr, [a, b, c])) ...
```

Works with objects and arrays:

```
var obj = [0, {a: [0, 'value', 2]}, 2]
get(obj, [1, 'a', 1]) //=> 'value'
get(obj, [1, 'a', 8]) //=> null
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if the values of one of the elements on the path was false?

Comment: Yes, I see now: there wouldn't be a false "on the path", because anything but a leaf node would be an array. Only a leaf node could be a false value. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Brilliant really. Is this the same as the get() in lodash?

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
if (arr && arr[a] && arr[a][b] && typeof arr[a][b][c] === 'undefined') { ...do something... }
```

or you can create a custom function

```js
function check(arr){
    let temp = arr;
    for(let i=1; i<arguments.length; i++){
        if(temp[arguments[i]] == undefined){
            return false;
        }
        temp = temp[arguments[i]];
    }
    return true;
}


let arr= [[[1], [2]], [3]];

console.log(check(arr, 0, 0));
console.log(check(arr, 0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. I selected another answer because it was more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

For sparse array check, just checking an item being `undefined` is not sufficient. However you can use the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator to test like

```
(a,b,c) in arr
```

```js
var a = [];
a[10] = 1;
b = 10;
console.log(1 in a)
console.log((1,2,3) in a)
console.log(b in a)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't address the problem in the question. This will tell you whether all the indexes in list are in the array; but I'm looking for whether the indexes in sequence are in the array. Not individually.

Comment: @NotoriousWebmaster No problem.. however i would advise you to rephrase the topic since "[sparse array](http://2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html)" (arrays with holes in them) means some of it's indices are missing **not** some of it's items are undefined. So `[undefined,3,undefined]` is not a sparse array.

Comment: so what would a sparse array look like, if not with undefined's strewn about?

Comment: @NotoriousWebmaster I would say `Array(3)` is sparse while `Array(3).fill()` is not. So on V8 console for instance `console.log(Array(3))` would look like `[undefined × 3]` while `Array(3).fill()` would look like `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` which means the first array have no keys (properties) at all while the latter has keys (0,1,2) assigned as `undefined` as values. A sparse array has holes in the sense of keys. In another words an array with `undefined` items don't qualify as a sparse array.

Comment: In fact, @Redu, I was dealing with a sparse array, where keys had not yet been added, and I needed to see if a given key was there or not. So it was, as per your definition, a sparse array. Thanks for clarifying that for me; I would have thought the undefined one was sparse as well.

Comment: `(1,2,3) in array` does _not_ check if all three indices are in that array, it will only check if `3` is in the array. That's the (near-useless) comma operator, and only the last value in the comma-sequence gets used.